# If $X$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $n$ then $P(0<X<2(n+1))\ge \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution

> If $X$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $n$ then $P(0<X<2(n+1))\ge \frac{n}{n+1}$.

I have tried to approach the problem but I just cannot figure out how to do it. I tried expanding the $e^{-x}$ but it just brought out a lo of terms which I don't know how to handle. Please help me out.

Edit: Ok guys I have tried the following using spaceisdarkGreen's suggestion. Now here is the part I have tried.

$$P(X>= 2(n+1) <= \frac{E(X)}{2(n+1)}$$
$$ E(X) = \int{\frac{e^{-x}x^{n+1}}{n!}}dx$$
$$=n+1$$
Therefore,

$$P(X>=2(n+1))<=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$ 1-P(0<X<2(n+1))<=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$ P(0<X<2(n+1))>=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you explain

Comment: $f_X$ is a Poisson distribution in which $n$ is the random variable, not $x$.

Comment: @Deep I think it's a Gamma/Erlang, not a Poisson and correct as written.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Hi I attempted to do this problem using your approach but I think I am still stuck. Can you tell me where I am going wrong. Check out the edit.

Comment: @testerpceSen I deleted my post cause I don't think it actually works, sorry. You should have $E(X) = n+1$, though, which makes things better, but not better enough.

Comment: @testerpceSen Ok, reposted, hope it actually works this time.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I was trying this exact same thing after looking it up on Wikipedia. :P And it wasn't working out.

Comment: @testerpceSen I'm pretty sure Chebyshev works. Actually wrote it out this time though I am rather tired.

Comment: It's a pointless question because (a) it is a hopeless bound, (b) one can find the probability exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chebyshev's inequality, often stated as $$ P(|X-E(X)| \ge a) \le \frac{Var(X)}{a^2}$$ for any random variable with finite expectation.

As a further hint, you can write $$P(X \ge 2(n+1)) = P((X-(n+1))\ge n+1) \le P(|X-(n+1)| \ge n+1).$$

Comment: Ok I made a mistake. Yea I got it thanks